What Triggers a VSTO Customization to load
We have some spreadsheets as part of a system, that when first loaded on a PC prompt if you would like to install the corresponding VSTO.
After the VSTO loads we have an extra tab in the ribbon that offers some controls.
Is there any way to inspect our excel document to see where the loading of the customization occurs. I.e. It doesnt (and shouldnt) open for every document which means there has to be something inside the excel document doing it, where can I view this.
I have looked through the VB editor and Add-In settings but haven't been able to find anything.
